# Xargo not running in nightly

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am trying to [follow some instructions to run my Rust code on a GPU](https://github.com/japaric/nvptx). However, I am unable to get it to compile.

Despite me installing Rust nightly, Xargo still claims that Rust nightly is not installed. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xargo twice and nothing changed.

```
xargo rustc --target nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -- --emit=asm
```

Output:

```
WARNING: the sysroot can't be built for the Stable channel. Switch to nightly.
   Compiling kernel v0.1.0 (file:///C:/Users/shado/Workspace/kernel)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `nvptx64-nvidia-cuda` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `kernel`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

```
rustc --version
```

Output:

```
rustc 1.25.0-nightly (15a1e2844 2018-01-20)
```

Comment: What happens if you run `xargo +nightly rustc --target nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -- --emit=asm`?

Comment: @Shepmaster It gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

Turns out all I had to run was `rustup default nightly` to solve this issue.

Comment: Interesting, when I set it to default to nightly it doesn't fix it.

`❯ rustup default nightly
info: using existing install for 'nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin'
info: default toolchain set to 'nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin'

  nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.69.0-nightly (d7948c843 2023-01-26)

❯ xargo build
ERROR: the sysroot can't be built for the Stable channel. Switch to nightly.`